# What does xpath="1" mean in HTML?

Tags: html, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath, chropath

In my design code, the following is written. I cannot understand what `xpath="1"` means here.

```
<select class="search-category" id="ddlTemp" name="Template" xpath="1">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

### In General

There is no standard interpretation of `xpath="1"` in HTML because there is no standard `xpath` attribute on a `select` element (or any other HTML element).  You've stumbled across some application's idiosyncratic markup; you'll have to consult the application's authors, documentation, or source code to learn the semantics of `xpath="1"`.

Note further that the proper way to add an application or user specific attribute would have been to name it with a `data-` prefix: `data-xpath`.

---

### Specific Application

There is an XPath utility, [ChroPath](https://autonomiq.io/chropath/), that runs as a browser extension and writes `xpath` (and `css`) attributes on elements.  **Credit:** [Randy Casburn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65367089/290085) to [What is the significance of the attribute xpath="1" while constructing locators for Selenium tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65365459/290085)

Comment: The isDisplayed method is returning false for this element. I was wondering if that has any connection with xpath=1.

Comment: Again, an `xpath` attribute has no semantics defined at the HTML level.

Comment: @Chandrima , Check ancestors - most probably you will find `hidden` attribute in some ancestor `div`

Comment: I'd have put my money with @kjhughes for a detailed answer :) however I have stumbled on both `xpath=1` and `xpath=2` and I.m still indecisive.

Comment: @DebanjanB: What application have you seen that writes or reads such attributes?

Comment: @kjhughes Can't recall atm but I'm sure I have answered a few of those relating to `xpath=1` let me check and get back to you.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Answer updated to include the name of the application responsible for creating `xpath="1"` attributes.  Thanks for posting the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65365459/290085) that uncovered the culprit.  ;-)

Comment: @kjhughes Let me checkout the answer.

Answer (score 0):

XPath='1' is not the part of your HTML, it is being added through chropath plugin. You have copied this html with opened chropath tab.
If you refresh the page and close the chropath tab, then you will not find xpath=1.