# What is the significance of the attribute xpath="1" while constructing locators for Selenium tests

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, chropath

Recently I stumbled on an element with an attribute `xpath="1"` within an angular based application.

HTML:

[image: xpath=1]

I'm unable to find any details about this attribute and it's possible impact and usage within a xpath/cssSelector for the Selenium based tests.

Can anyone help me out in any directions please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xpath = 1 in html means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65324794/xpath-1-in-html-means)

Comment: I have searched the angular code base and found nothing that refers to `xpath="1"`.

Comment: wp78de: That's related, but there DebanjanB and I still wondered where these attributes were coming from, thus his question here.  I've updated my [general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65325284/290085) with a note about ChroPath and credited @RandyCasbum with a link to his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65367089/290085) here.   Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That attribute (xpath="1") is placed there by a browser extension named [CHROPATH](https://autonomiq.io/chropath/). It is provided by a feature they call *Dynamic Attribute Support*.

Scolling down the page one will find a text description of how to use the tool.

Scroll to Note: at the bottom of the page, or search for "Note:" within the page text. Take special attention to note #2. The entire note reads:

> Note:
>
> 1. For one selector only, change the dropdown value from selectors to rel XPath/abs Xpath/CSS sel in header.
> 2. Tool will add xpath/css attribute to all the matching node(s) as per their sequential occurrence. For example, a matching node
>    appearing second in the list will have **xpath=2**. And if verifying CSS
>    then it will add css=2.
> 3. Supports only those iframe which are from the same src.

Comment: So `xpath=1` or `xpath=2` isn't part of the actual element as far as the original HTML of the element is concerned. So can't be used for Selenium tests, agree @kjhughes ?

Comment: This is ChroPath creator, Sanjay Kumar. I have stopped development and support on ChroPath so it might not be working properly. Please upgrade to my new xpath tool SelectorsHub.

Comment: Good to know -Thanks Sanjay.

Answer (score 0):

XPath="#" indicates the occurrence of the matching node on the web page. It is added by the plugin when you verify your own xpath. It add XPath = '1' for inspected element. I believe chropath is deprecated now and no support available on it.